# Is there any way to save and HTML table including forms without creating a model in Django?

Tags: django, sqlite, html-table, django-forms

I have created a table with django forms in it. The forms do get data from the database, from two different models. Since this form has 42 fields consisting of 7 days and 6 shifts, i would love to save it as the table it is rendered. Is there any way to do this?

forms.py

```
class EditSchedule(forms.Form):
def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    super(EditSchedule, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    for k in range(1,8):
        for i in range(1,7):
            self.fields["S"+str(i)+"D"+str(k)] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=get_my_choices(i,k))
            self.fields["S"+str(i)+"D"+str(k)].widget.attrs.update({"class":"form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible"})
```

html file

```
<div class="box">
<form  method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
<div class="box-body">
    <div class="table-container table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover dataTable" role="grid" >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class = "shicht"><h3>Schicht</h3></th>
                    <th class = "montag"><h3>Montag</h3></th>
                    <th class = "dienstag"><h3>Dienstag</h3></th>
                    <th class = "mittwoch"><h3>Mittwoch</h3></th>
                    <th class = "donnerstag"><h3>Donnerstag</h3></th>
                    <th class = "freitag"><h3>Freitag</h3></th>
                    <th class = "samstag"><h3>Samstag</h3></th>
                    <th class = "sonntag"><h3>Sonntag</h3></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="even">
                    <td class="shicht">Schicht 1</td>
                    <td class="montag">{{ form.S1D1 }}</td>
                    <td class="dienstag">{{ form.S1D2 }}</td>
                    <td class = "Mittwoch">{{ form.S1D3 }}</td>
                    <td class = "donnerstag">{{ form.S1D4 }}</td>
                    <td class = "freitag">{{ form.S1D5 }}</td>
                    <td class ="samstag">{{ form.S1D6 }}</td>
                    <td class ="sonntag">{{ form.S1D7 }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="odd">
                    <td class="shicht">Schicht 2</td>
                    <td class="montag">{{ form.S2D1 }}</td>
                    <td class="dienstag">{{ form.S2D2 }}</td>
                    <td class = "Mittwoch">{{ form.S2D3 }}</td>
                    <td class = "donnerstag">{{ form.S2D4 }}</td>
                    <td class = "freitag">{{ form.S2D5 }}</td>
                    <td class ="samstag">{{ form.S2D6 }}</td>
                    <td class ="sonntag">{{ form.S2D7 }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="even">
                    <td class="shicht">Schicht 3</td>
                    <td class="montag">{{ form.S3D1 }}</td>
                    <td class="dienstag">{{ form.S3D2 }}</td>
                    <td class = "Mittwoch">{{ form.S3D3 }}</td>
                    <td class = "donnerstag">{{ form.S3D4 }}</td>
                    <td class = "freitag">{{ form.S3D5 }}</td>
                    <td class ="samstag">{{ form.S3D6 }}</td>
                    <td class ="sonntag">{{ form.S3D7 }}</td>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [raw queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/sql/) for this.
For capture the form filds you can use the "clean" methods in the base form class see [forms validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/validation/)

Comment: Thanks!!  is it possible to use these queries in a Formview?

Comment: Yes you can overwrite the base class methods. define a post method in your FormView and return the proper response.

Comment: Could you provide an example on how to implement this on the first form S1D1? I have no idea how to start.

Comment: you can define a method in your form, override the **clean()** method in the form class to obtain the data. but you must pass it from your view. sorry i can't help more in this moment. i see this in google, Maybe it gives you an idea 
https://gist.github.com/vero4karu/ec0f82bb3d302961503d

Comment: I have tried the github example. But i save only one id.